# copy notifications from notification drop down menu ( iOS 5.0+ available)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'd like to develop an iphone application that will copy Facebook and Twitter notifications from notification center.
How can I get facebook and twitter notifications from notification center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app does not have access to any other app notifications. You cannot access notifications other than your own (actually, you can only access the notification the user clicked in. Even if you have raised multiple notifications).

You'd have to access the twitter/Facebook account directly to grab the latest information.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, there is no acces to the notification center.

You app will only get the notification that the users clicked on, either from the notification center or when your app is openen. You can't even see other notification that where received for your app.